# How to change the State in React Redux without mutating data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm aware of "sacred" data is and how dangerous it might get if handled incorrectly; that's why in my app, I'm in a position now where I need to handle a nested long JSON object (that repsents my app state) and it's already a headache to me to get in and out of the nodes/values that need to be amended. I was thinking of including `Immutable.js`. The question now is: how do I adapt my reducers, actions, state, etc?

Here's an extract of my state when it comes from the `MongoDB` database:

```
"shops": [
        {
            "shopId": "5a0c67e9fd3eb67969316cff",
            "picture": "http://placehold.it/150x150",
            "name": "Zipak",
            "email": "leilaware@zipak.com",
            "city": "Rabat",
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -6.74736,
                    33.81514
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "shopId": "5a0c6b55fd3eb67969316d9d",
            "picture": "http://placehold.it/150x150",
            "name": "Genekom",
            "email": "leilaware@genekom.com",
            "city": "Rabat",
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -6.74695,
                    33.81594
                ]
            }
        },
        ...
```

When a certain action (end-user hits a "Like" button) is triggered, I need to add an attribute to the related `Shop` object, so it'd become like this:

```
{
    "shopId": "5a0c67e9fd3eb67969316cff",
    "picture": "http://placehold.it/150x150",
    "name": "Zipak",
    "email": "leilaware@zipak.com",
    "city": "Rabat",
    "liked": true,
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -6.74736,
            33.81514
        ]
    }
},
```

Now, I manage to add the `liked` attribute to the individual `Shop` object, but when I want to change/amend the state (group of all `Shop` objects), I get the object duplicated (the new one with the `liked` attribute and the old one). To avoid this mess, I want to handle these operations using `Immutable.js` to make sure everything is clean and proper.

Where do I start from? Do I convert the state to an `Immutable.js` Map? List?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `Immutable.js` you can use [`immutability-helper`](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) which has an [`update`](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper#update) function returns the updated value without mutating the original value.

`immutability-helper` has a syntax inspired from MongoDB so getting used to it shouldn't be very hard for you.

For your case, you can modify your state with the below sample,

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const id = '5a0c67e9fd3eb67969316cff'; // id of the item you need to update
const newState = update(state, {
  shops: {
    $apply: (item) => {
      if (item.shopId !== id) return item
      return {
        ...item,
        liked: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply reduce your array of identified shops to an object on fetch success. It's a good practice to do so for any list of unique items to avoid the O(n) complexity of find functions and to mutate your state in a simpler way.

Reduce shops on fetch success in your shops reducer :

```
shops.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.id] = item
        return obj;
}, {})
```

It will then be easy to manipulate your object inside your shops reducer on any action such as a like success :

```
return { 
    ...state, 
   [action.shopId]: { 
       ...state[action.shopId], 
       liked: true,
    },
}
```

Comment: It will turn the shops array [{ id: 1, name: 'A' }, { id: 2, name: 'B' }] into one object { 1: { id: 1, name: 'A' }, 2:  { id: 2, name: 'B' }}.

Comment: You will also need to use Object.values(state.shops) wherever you were mapping the redux state to your component's props instead of passing it directly.